# How can I wait for a promise to resolved then obtain the value and put it in other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, dialogflow-es

I have trouble getting `stringReply` value into my `app.post`(using Express).
For what I know I think is that the code has completely executed before the promise is resolved, thus giving me a undefined value when I tried to log `stringReply`.

```
fetch(osURL, setting)
.then(loadRes)
.then(logger)
```

```
function loadRes (res){
  return res.json();
}
```

```
async function logger (reply){
  let stringReply = await reply.answer;
  sendingReply(stringReply);

  return stringReply
}
```

```
function sendingReply(stringReply){  
  let response = {
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            stringReply
          ]
        }
      }
    ]//fulfillmentMessageObj
  };//response3
  console.log(stringReply); //I can still get the value I wanted here
  return response
}
```

```
app.post('/', function( req, res){

console.log(stringReply);
//obtain value here before posting the value to other place
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I think there is a problem with your logger function: The result of sendingReply is not handled. the response object never logged or received.

Comment: Is this all your code? Is the `fetch().then().then()` part of a function, or how is it being called from inside your `app.post()` handler?

Comment: because at the ```app.post``` I received a undefined value when i console.log but when on the ```function sendingReply()``` I managed to receive a value string from the console.log

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't about waiting for the Promise - it sounds like you have a variable scoping issue (and, separately, a problem with understanding return values). `stringReply` is undefined in the `app.post()` callback because it isn't set there.

You're able to log it in `sendingReply(stringReply)` because you're passing a parameter named `stringReply`. Even tho these have the same name, since this is a parameter, the name of that parameter is available inside the function.

In your `logger()` function, you declare `stringReply` as a local variable. When you "return" it, you're not returning the variable - you're returning the **value** of the variable.

There are, however, additional problems with your code.

Since the call to `fetch()` is outside your `app.post()` callback function, it gets called when your code is first run, but *not* when the '/' endpoint is hit. While this is sometimes intentional - it probably isn't in your case.

Furthermore, you're not storing the result from the call to the `fetch().then().then()` chain. So you probably want that block of code to read something like

```
const loggerResult = fetch(osURL, setting)
  .then(loadRes)
  .then(logger)
```

Even if you were storing the result, it probably isn't the result you want. This is because `logger()` appears to call `sendingReply()`, but *it* doesn't do anything with the result either. That function might need to do something with the reply as well. Perhaps something like

```
async function logger (reply){
  let stringReply = await reply.answer;
  cont ret = sendingReply(stringReply);

  return ret
}
```

There are other problems with your code that are confusing as well. Why, for example is `logger()` an async function? And why does it appear to be using `await` on something that isn't a function? None of that seems necessary in your sample code.